# Does a body move with retarded motion on inclined plane when no gravity is present but friction is?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

Let us consider two cases. Common for both of them is that gravity is $0$.

So, if there is an inclined plane

- case 1: is frictionless, and
- case 2: other one is not.

Would the body move with constant velocity in case 1 and not in case 2 since net force is not force.

The thing is that if friction is present but no gravity.Would the Body even be in contact with the inclined plane surface.Would it even matter to consider  case 2 like that?

Comment: What does it mean to "move retard"?

Comment: @nasu In retarder motion or acceleration decreasing

Comment: @nasu I have edited it.

Comment: If there is no gravity, why is the body moving on the incline?

Comment: I thought just like a body moves in space , it will also move on inclined plane.

Comment: How will it start to move? What are the initial conditions? If you just leave it at the top on the incline (or anywhere else on the incline) it will just stay there.  Even the concept of being on the plane is ambiguous.

Comment: @nasu you give it a force of 10N for 1sec and after that it moves

Comment: @nasu Therefore , it will then a acquire speed.

Comment: What is the direction of the 10 N force?

Comment: @nasu in such a way directions should be that it goes along the inclined plane.

Comment: Then the plane is irrelevant. It will move the same with  or without the incline there.  There is no interaction between the two objects.

Comment: @nasu yes,I was not sure about it.Just like Mr.Mysterious has given a proof.I have understood it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The force of friction for a moving object is given by the kinetic friction

$F_K = \mu F_\perp$,

which consists of the friction coefficient $\mu$ and the normal force $F_\perp$. The normal force is the force that pushs the object in question onto the surface and usually this is simply given by the gravitational force perpendicular to the surface. Since you consider gravity to be absent,

$F_\perp = 0 \to F_K = 0$,

it follows that there is also no force of friction (note that we do not even have to consider any value for $\mu$). Which in turn means that in both cases the object continues to move with constant velocity.

Comment: Ok.Thank you . .